# Spring security access with multiple roles

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I want to define access for some pages for user who has one of following roles (ROLE1 or ROLE2)

I'm trying to configure this in my spring security xml file as following:

```
<security:http entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint" access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" use-expressions="true">
        <!-- skipped configuration -->
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/api/myUrl*" access="hasRole('ROLE1') or hasRole('ROLE2')" />

        <!-- skipped configuration -->
    </security:http>
```

I've tried various ways like:

```
access="hasRole('ROLE1, ROLE2')"
access="hasRole('ROLE1', 'ROLE2')"
access="hasAnyRole('[ROLE1', 'ROLE2]')"
```

etc

but nothing seems to be working.

I'm keep getting exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes:
```

or

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to parse expression 'hasAnyRole(['ROLE1', 'ROLE2'])'
```

how should it be configured?

Thanks

Comment: Did you put <http ... use-expressions="true"> ?

Comment: yes. it can be seen on my configuration above

Comment: Sorry my bad. Also did you try hasAnyRole ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The problem was that I configured custom `access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"`
and didn't pass one of the voters.

Solved by adding `org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter` to `accessDecisionManager` bean.

Comment: great! which version of hasRole() did you use? hasRole('ROLE1', 'ROLE2') ?

Comment: Cant remember now...but one of them for sure)

Answer (score 51):

How try with `,` separate. See doc [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/core-web-filters.html) and [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html).

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/api/myUrl*" access="ROLE1,ROLE2"/>
```

OR

```
hasAnyRole('ROLE1','ROLE2')
```

Comment: `hasAnyRole` is what I needed. Thank you.