# Spring security validate with webservice and retrieve roles from Database

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to accomplish something quite simple and I'm sure that once I get this, I'll call myself a Donkey. However, here are the steps that I'm trying to perform in sudo code.

```
step1
--get username and password from login form

step2
-- send username and password to web service

step3 
-- if the return from the service equals "N" show error else if the return from the service equals "Y" then authenticate a user and query database for user roles.

step4 
-- if the user role is not allowed to see page show error page else continue to page.
```

I have tried several tutorials and I'm just failing miserably. I suspect because everything I've seen is configuration related or annotation related so is a bit hard to me to understand at what point is the user being authenticated.

I've tried

http://www.ekiras.com/2016/04/authenticate-user-with-custom-user-details-service-in-spring-security.html

http://o7planning.org/en/10603/spring-mvc-security-and-spring-jdbc-tutorial
[Spring security access with multiple roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010597/spring-security-access-with-multiple-roles)

my biggest problem is step3 above. How can I do that? I simply don't understand how to authenticate the user and add several roles to that user to stay within the constratint of spring.

Comment: Is your web service only returning Y and N for success and failures? If yes, then it's hard to derive what kind of error you want to return to client like User do not exists, user credentials are invalid or user not active in db, ideally web service should return proper response along with user data (atleast roles) so that you do not need to query DB again just to fetch roles.

Comment: Thanks for the response apollo. If service response equals "n" than I would return and "invalid username /password" error. So my real problem here is step 3 above. I thinks but I'm not sure , is that I need to use the user detail service somehow , but I'm not sure of what I'm doing.

Comment: @Miguel but are you using spring-security? Because if you are using it, you dont need a webservice, you have to add your implementation of UserDetailsService

Comment: @cralfaro yes im trying to use spring security but the examples ive seen usually have the user hard coded in xml and they get one single role from the database. My hurdle is that I need to call a web service and separately a database, then use that as the source for my authentication. In .net using form authentication I would have called a web-service and than when the service responds I would have selected from a DB to get the user roles. I'm trying to replicate that simple functionality.

Comment: @Miguel Ok i understand, then i think i know how to fix it, you know in spring security you need to implement the interface UserDetailsService, and implement inside the method loadUserByUsername(), then in the implementation of that method you are going to do 2 things, 1 call your WS. If the response is Y then go to DB and find the user, and return the UserDetails, if the response is N, you have to create an exception UserNotFoundException

Comment: @cralfaro You basically gave me the answer. Can you post it up as an answer so I may give you the credit? It's only fair, thank you so much for the response I spent 3 days doing this simple task. I guess is just part of learning.

Comment: @Miguel Thanks Miguel :) i will explain it in a response so can be useful for some more people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using Spring-Security you could use this structure:

[In my case is annotation based and with Spring-Boot.]

You will need an ApplicationSecurity class which extends from WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
public class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailSecurityService userDetailSecurityService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/static").permitAll().anyRequest()
                .fullyAuthenticated();

        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error=1")
                .permitAll().defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .successHandler(
                        new NoRedirectSavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
                .and()
                    .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionAuthenticationErrorUrl("/notauthorized")
                    .invalidSessionUrl("/notauthorized")
                .and()
                    .logout()
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID", "SESSION")
                .permitAll();
    }

    //If you want to add some encoder method to store your passwords
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailSecurityService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }


    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new MD5PasswordEncoder();
    }


    private class NoRedirectSavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends
            SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

        final Integer SESSION_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS = 30 * 60; /** 30 min */

        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
                                            HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
                throws ServletException, IOException {

            request.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(SESSION_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS);
            response.sendRedirect("/");
        }
    }
}
```

Your class UserDetailsSecurityService must to implements UserDetailsService, which is a Spring-Security class and need to override the method loadUserByUsername()

```
@Service
public class UserDetailSecurityService implements UserDetailsService{

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        /*Here in your case would call your WebService and check if the result is Y/N and return the UserDetails object with all roles, etc
        If the user is not valid you could throw an exception
        */
        return userService.findByUsername(username);
    }
}
```